# SQL query get row from table A when it's column value is not in table B and calculate something that will be stored in table B

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

One is called

```
trades
```

The other one is called

```
yields
```

Trades has the following columns

```
common_id (which marks the trades that belong together)
type (buy or sell)
amount
```

yields has the following columns

```
common_id (which is the one from trades but will only appear once now)
yield
```

The yield field is calculated as follows: if the trade is a "buy" then its value is subtracted, if the trade is a "sell" then the value is added.

So basically a couple of trades are belonging together which is shown by the common_id field. From those trades I want to calculate the yield.
Then do the same for the next trades that belong together and so on.

Now here is the problem. The "trades" table is build up initially and can become very huge, after that I want to build up the second table "yield". For initial build up this is easy. The problem is how do I do this when the application is interupted and I already have both tables.

So I need the recods of "trades" with the common_ids that are not already in "yields", after that I calculate the yield and store it in "yields".

Anyone some ideas?

Regards

Comment: Mysql or SQL-Server? that are two different thinks.

Comment: Sorry ment mysql, fixed that

Comment: `So I need the recods of "trades" with the common_ids that are not already in "yields", after that I calculate the yield and store it in "yields".` What if you have a particular trade whose value is not recorded in `yields`? That is, `trades.common_id` exists in `yields`, but not all the individual trades' values?

Answer (score 0):

You could handle this in a single `insert` statement:

```
INSERT INTO yields
(SELECT   common_id, SUM (CASE type WHEN 'buy' THEN -1 * amount
                                    WHEN 'sell' THEN amount
                                    ELSE 0 -- just a precaution
                          END)
 FROM     trades
 WHERE    common_id NOT IN (SELECT common_id FROM yields)
 GROUP BY common_id)
```

Comment: but this query does only add a sign to amount of one trade but I have for example 3 trades with the same common_id "buy" "buy" "sell" so it should do the following: -buy1.amount -buy2.amount + sell1.amount. Can this be done in a query too, or do I need to do this in an external program?

Answer (score 0):

i would delete the table yields and build it up initially again. I think it is the easiest way and will also run faster then running through all lines